# C#-How to execute only top button of RibbonSplitButton ignoring the drop down button from outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have a RibbonSplitButton in my outlook ribbon having a button and drop down button.I want to trigger only the top button ignoring the drop down.

If I try to trigger the button with execute method from Outlook add-in it is throwing error because both the button name is same.

`Error in IAccessible.accDoDefaultAction: MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED`.

Can anyone help me to get the only top button clicked.

Comment: Where does the button come from? Is it a built-in control or a custom one?

Comment: Its Built-in button. I know only the Label of the button. In the split button both top and drop down button name are same "Add with Template". If i try to execute like this:   `Redemption.SafeRibbonControl newControl = cRibbon.Controls.Item("Add With Template");  newControl.execute();` It is throwing the above error

Comment: It is a custom button  but i don't know the object of that button to perform object.execute();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exceute a built-in ribbon control programmatically you can use the [ExceuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRary/ff862419.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the CommandBars class. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons and splitButtons. On failure it returns E_InvalidArg for an invalid IdMso, and E_Fail for controls that are not enabled or not visible.

The following sample executes the Copy button.

```
  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(“Copy”)
```

But if it is a custom control - the Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for that. You may try to use [Accessibility API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Sorry little confusion it is custom button but i don't know the object of that button to perform object.execute(); .

Comment: the Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for that. You may try to use [Accessibility API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).